# Update statement with a function

Tags: ssms, update, functions

I'm just curious. I was trying to optimize an update statement with a function

Ex

```
update circle set area = fnGetArea(radius) where ...<bunch of conditions>
```

This update went 5-10mins and when I removed the fnGetArea, it went 5-10 seconds!

How did that happen...?

I want to google it but I'm not sure what to type in.

Please enlighten me! :D

Thanks in advance

Comment: First thing is to check the function `fnGetArea` there must be something wrong and the next check is for, is there any `trigger` on `update` and then at last also have a look at indexes on table.

Comment: I don't think there's something wrong with fnGetArea. It just compute for the area then return. And yes, there are appropriate indexes and trigger in the table...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? What does the execution plan say? Do you have an index on `id`? How many rows will be updated with that statement? What exactly is `fnGetArea()` doing?

Comment: I have update the tags and also my sample query... I haven't seen the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I found [this link](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/42006/create-function-executes-during-the-update-stateme.html), which contains the answer:

> ...by having this as a function on your update, you are essentially
>   *calling the function as many number of times as there are rows in the
>   table*. This is not the best way to do this, and is known as row-by-row
>   processing, rather than set-based.
>
> Try and take the processing that the function is doing and apply it to
>   the table in one go rather than this one-at-a-time approach.